# How to convert a BeautifulSoup list array into a String?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, beautifulsoup

I want to extract 4 numbers from a webpage with BeautifulSoup to later save those values in one line as a String in CSV format.

Extracting and saving the values to variables is working fine with BeautifulSoups findAll() function. The 4 values I need are within `<p>` tags with the css-style attribute `"font-size: 13pt"`. Those values are saved in the list array linkData[].

I just don't know how I can save those variables in one line as a String. Right now, I am always getting line breaks, which is a problem, because I need the CSV output to be: `var0,var1,var2,var3`

Instead of:

```
var0
var1
var2
var3
```

I have already tried several things which I added to my code below. I almost got it working with my third approach but unfortunately, the encoding seems to be wrong if I use this option.

I need `987, 1002, 278, 19`, but the output of print() is `(u'\n987\n', u'\n1002\n', u'\n278\n', u'\n19\n')`. Is there an option to change the encoding?

I am fairly new to BeautifulSoup so any help is highly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open('http://www.example.com')

html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

linkData = soup.findAll("p", {"style": "font-size: 13pt;"})

var0 = linkData[0].text
var1 = linkData[1].text
var2 = linkData[2].text
var3 = linkData[3].text

# Approach 1: Just print variables comma-separated
print var0, var1

# Approach 2: Using join to concatenate the variables 
linkDataList = [var0, var1, var2, var3]
str1 = ''.join(linkDataList)
print str1

# Approach 3: Use print() function
print(var0, var1, var2, var3)
```

Best regards!

Comment: As indicated at the printout, your data has new-line whitespace around it (`\n`) so just strip it:  `print(var0.strip(), var1.strip(), var2.strip(), var3.strip())`

Comment: @zwer Thanks a lot for your quick help, I got it working now. Such an easy fix :) EyuelDK I don't want to disclose that specific URL but I created a modified version with a different URL for you to check below. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just strip all the blank spaces using `str.strip()`  when you define the variables.

```
var0 = linkData[0].text.strip()
var1 = linkData[1].text.strip()
var2 = linkData[2].text.strip()
var3 = linkData[3].text.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help as well!